# Azure Service Bus get messages from queue using CLI?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Is it possible to read messages from Azure Service Bus queue using az CLI?

Comment: no. why would you want to do that?

Comment: why not? My application fully relies on Azure service principal (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) to interact with Azure using CLI.

Comment: @foo-bar I would ask the same as Peter. Why would you do it? In production system, a DLQ-ed message is a message you need to action. Retrieving it using CLI you'd need to be able to inspect the contents and then action. CLI is not the tool to use. There are better tools such as [ServiceBus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest) or [Queue Explorer](https://www.cogin.com/mq/) that would allow you to peek, inspect, fix/resubmit.

Comment: It should be relatively straight forward to implement your own peek functionality if that's what you want.

Comment: It's useful for debugging to be able to peek through the CLI, I was also surprised that it's not a feature of the CLI

Comment: I think the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest) could be used for that along with [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest).

Comment: Peeking the queue from the CLI seems totally reasonable to me. Funny that the azure cli doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `AWS` has many more options and ways to accessing data plane in its CLI than `az-cli` offers in `Azure`. I looked in various documentation, az-cli reference and could not find direct way of dealing with it.

It seems to me that the way to deal with it is to access it through REST interface, here is a working example I just tested```:

https://gist.github.com/wkaczurba/cd1f22df3bec19f0d1ce61965bcaba5f

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Execute az login first.

# Replace these ones with correct ones:
SERVICE_BUS_NAME_SPACE=sapps-eventdriven-servicebus # Name of service bus name space (not the queue)
RESOURCE_GROUP=sapps-eventdriven
QUEUE_NAME="upper-case"
SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_URL=https://sapps-eventdriven-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/upper-case

# Maybe not a good practice but should work without creating new Shared Access Policies... - using (RootManageSharedAccessKey)
SHARED_ACCESS_KEY=$(az servicebus namespace authorization-rule keys list \
        --resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP} \
        --namespace-name ${SERVICE_BUS_NAME_SPACE} \
        --name RootManageSharedAccessKey \
        --query primaryKey \
        --output tsv)

SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_NAME=RootManageSharedAccessKey
SHARED_ACCESS_KEY=$PRIMARY_KEY

# Generate SAS key - based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token 
EXPIRY=${EXPIRY:=$((60 * 60 * 24))} # Default token expiry is 1 day
ENCODED_URI=$(echo -n $SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_URL | jq -s -R -r @uri)
TTL=$(($(date +%s) + $EXPIRY))
UTF8_SIGNATURE=$(printf "%s\n%s" $ENCODED_URI $TTL | iconv -t utf8)
HASH=$(echo -n "$UTF8_SIGNATURE" | openssl sha256 -hmac $SHARED_ACCESS_KEY -binary | base64)
ENCODED_HASH=$(echo -n $HASH | jq -s -R -r @uri)
SAS_TOKEN=$(echo -n "SharedAccessSignature sr=$ENCODED_URI&sig=$ENCODED_HASH&se=$TTL&skn=$SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_NAME")

# Execute CALL to REST-API
curl --location --request POST 'https://sapps-eventdriven-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/upper-case/messages/head' \
    --header "Authorization: $SAS_TOKEN" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d ''
```

Hope it helps.